# Set "wait" in KNIME scraper

Tags: ajax, web-scraping, scrape, knime

I'm building a news scraper for a project, and I found my way through most of the sites, but one is giving me the headache, because whenever I try to bulk-extract the articles contents, most of html of the links won't load.
I even tried in python, same obsolete results. 
My question is:
 how can I set a "wait until content is loaded"? I am reading that some Ajax thing may be needed to load first.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for are the [Selenium Nodes](https://seleniumnodes.com). They are particularly targeted for extracting data from Ajax-based websites, where content is loaded via JavaScript code.

You can find some example workflows e.g. here:

- https://nodepit.com/server/seleniumnodes.com

Comment: They are paid, and I'm doing a non-paid project. Also, there should be another way. :)

Comment: There is a free trial license you should ask. Also if youre making money with the project you should consider paying for good software

Comment: It's purely for research I'd want to publish, but there ain't no money in it. :) Also, I could always pay for someone to scrape it for me. The bug is to do it on my own with tools at hand, i.e. free. :)

Comment: There is a workflow node called Wait which may come in handy, only if I knew how to use it.